# Bash: replacing a column by another and using AWK to print specific order

Tags: bash, awk

I have a dummy file that looks like so:

```
a ID_1 S1 S2
b SNP1 1 0
c SNP2 2 1
d SNP3 1 0
```

I want to replace the contents of column 2 by the corresponding line number. My file would then look like so:

```
a 1 S1 S2
b 2 1 0
c 3 2 1
d 4 1 0
```

I can do this with the following command:

```
cut -f 1,3-4 -d " " file.txt | awk '{print $1 " " FNR " " $2,$3}'
```

My question is, is there a better way of doing this? In particular, the real file I am working on has 2303 columns. Obviously I don't want to have to write:

```
cut -f 1,3-2303 -d " " file.txt | awk '{print $1 " " FNR " " $2,$3,$4,$5 ETC}'
```

Is there a way to tell awk to print from column 2 to the last column without having to write all the names?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do

```
$ awk '{$2=FNR} 1' file.txt 
a 1 S1 S2
b 2 1 0
c 3 2 1
d 4 1 0
```

change second column and print the changed record. Default OFS is single space which is what you need here

the above command is idiomatic way to write

```
awk '{$2=FNR} {print $0}' file.txt
```

you can think of simple `awk` program as `awk 'cond1{action1} cond2{action2} ...'`

only if `cond1` evaluates to true, `action1` is executed and so on. If `action` portion is omitted, `awk` by default prints input record. `1` is simply one way to write always true condition

See [Idiomatic awk](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/) mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info for more such idioms

Comment: Great, it works! Quick question, what does the 1 outside of the {} mean?

Comment: Everything is "code" so replace "code1", etc. with "action1", etc. for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may also help you in same here.

```
awk '{sub(/.*/,FNR,$2)} 1'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
a 1 S1 S2
b 2 1 0
c 3 2 1
d 4 1 0
```

***Explanation:*** It's explanation will be simple, using `sub` utility of `awk` to substitute everything in `$2`(second field) with `FNR` which is out of the box variable for `awk` to represent the current line number of any Input_file then mentioning `1` will print the current line of Input_file.

Comment: There's no reason to favor `sub(/.*/,FNR,$2)` over `$2=FNR`, the output will be the same but the sub() will make your code slower.

Comment: thanks, that's also good to know, I didn't know about this sub utility!